# Using JDBC for establish Connection

Tags: jdbc

i am faacing a trouble when trying to establish connection using JDBC when i run the code from google dev :

```js
var server = 'serverip';
var port = 3306;
var dbName = 'dbname';
var username = 'dbuser';
var password = 'dbpass';

var url = 'jdbc:Mysql://'http://serverip:3306'/'+ dbname;


function readData() {

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM mt_merchant');
  var metaData=results.getMetaData();
  var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();

  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DB Data');
 
 sheet.clearContents();
  var arr=[];

  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
    arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
  }

  sheet.appendRow(arr);

while (results.next()) {
  arr=[];
  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
    arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
  }
  sheet.appendRow(arr);
}

results.close();
stmt.close();
sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, numCols+1);
}
```

So that means that connection cannot be establish but i cannot figure out where is the problem ?

Comment: replace variable with yours. eg, a server IP is wrong here, it shouldn't be string `serverip`. An so on with dbname, dbuser, dbpass

Comment: OFC i did that , but it's still not working ... 

the code keep loading on script.google.com ... Running without any sign of executing it without showing ANY ERRORS  .

Comment: Now i am getting "ReferenceError: MasterData is not defined "

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved !

i forgot to authorize ip ranges X) ! Thank u !